# Why do elements from html to js file go as objects

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
var toplama_islemi = (document.getElementById("toplama_islemi").style.display ="none");

var cıkarma_islemi = (document.getElementById("cıkarma_islemi").style.display ="none");

var carpma_islemi = (document.getElementById("carpma_islemi").style.display ="none");

var bolme_islemi = (document.getElementById("bolme_islemi").style.display ="none");
```

And why are there two equal signs here?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking here, or how the title is connected to the code you've provided.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Unexplained code dumps don't make great comments.

Comment: Why are there two equal signs (per line)? The second one is assigning `none` to the `style.display` property and the first one is assigning the result of the assignment (`none`) to the variable on that line. This is likely a bug. Please improve your question to include expected vs actual behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't comparisons. They're assignments. The styles are applied to the elements, and then the elements' style property values are assigned to variables.

Here's a demonstration.

```js
setTimeout(function() {

  var toplama_islemi = (document.getElementById("toplama_islemi").style.display = "none");
  var cıkarma_islemi = (document.getElementById("cıkarma_islemi").style.display = "none");
  var carpma_islemi = (document.getElementById("carpma_islemi").style.display = "none");
  var bolme_islemi = (document.getElementById("bolme_islemi").style.display = "none");
  
  console.log({toplama_islemi, cıkarma_islemi, carpma_islemi, bolme_islemi});

}, 2000);
```

```html
<p>Wait for it...</p>

<div id="toplama_islemi">toplama_islemi</div>
<div id="cıkarma_islemi">cıkarma_islemi</div>
<div id="carpma_islemi">carpma_islemi</div>
<div id="bolme_islemi">bolme_islemi</div>
```

Everything is an object in JavaScript (except primitive values). If you don't want the style property values returned, do the steps separately:

```
var toplama_islemi = document.getElementById("toplama_islemi");
toplama.style.display = "none";
```

Now the element is assigned to the variable instead.

Comment: Here's a `console.log` trick to save some typing: `console.log({toplama_islemi, cıkarma_islemi, carpma_islemi, carpma_islemi )`